# Date conversion in angular

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9, angular10

I am working on an angular application. I have a date in the format 2020-08-11T19:00:00 but I want date in `1-Jun-2021` format. I tried to do it using date pipe as follows:

```
{{2020-08-11T19:00:00  | date:'d-MMM-y'}}
```

But it is giving parse error as

```
"Parser Error: Unexpected token 'T19'"
```

How can I do that using date pipe?

Comment: {{ "2020-08-11T19:00:00"  | date:'d-MMM-y'}}

Comment: Try this `{{'2020-08-11T19:00:00'  | date:'d-MMM-y'}}`. It looks like you forgot quotes around your date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting quotes around the date.

```js
{{ '2020-08-11T19:00:00'  | date:'d-MMM-y'}}
```

> > DatePipe is executed only when it detects a pure change to the input value. A pure change is either a change to a primitive input value (such as String, Number, Boolean, or Symbol), or a changed object reference (such as Date, Array, Function, or Object).

Ref : [Angular DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Answer (score 0):

You misplaced double quote `"` before and after of date input that's why it seems to this error.

```
 {{ "2020-08-11T19:00:00" | date:'d-MMM-y'}}
```